# ApiRTC token authentication

Tags: javascript, jwt, webrtc

I am trying to use token authentication with no success. I am wondering if anyone succeed in doing so, as the official ApiRTC documentation is weak on that topic.

1) I have activated secret key below from - Credentials screen

2) For token validation I have setup a service from API - Token authentication screen

3) I have the below code to create the user agent

```
function createUserAgent(token) {
    ua = new apiRTC.UserAgent({
        uri: 'token:' + token
    });

    ua.register({
        id : useragentId
    }).then(uaRegistered)
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Registration error");
    });
}

function uaRegistered(session) {
        console.log("Registration OK");
}
```

4) This initializes a request to below address. And it fails with HTTP 401

GET https://cloud.apizee.com/api/v2/checkToken?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhNWQxN2M1ZTVjOWZkYmRiNDJhYTgzMTJlMWQxMmEwYiIsImF1ZCI6ImFwaVJUQyIsImp0aSI6ImE5ZjU4NmNlLTcxMDctNDgxMS04ODYwLTQ5MjY4ODY2NjhiYiIsImlhdCI6MTU1OTg5OTA5MSwiZXhwIjoxNTU5OTAyNjkxLCJncmFudHMiOnsiaWRlbnRpdHkiOiJjbGk5OTQxOTgxNTgifX0.ZfQs_HgUXOWhCAlXB6fTMKhbT-pFslb9MK_JvXu2U5A 401 (Unauthorized)

5) I have also seen that no requests are made to my token validation service.

Thanks

edit: updates according to the answer

```
function createUserAgent(token) {

    apiRTC.setLogLevel(apiRTC.LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG);

    var registerInformation = {};
    registerInformation.id = useragentId;
    registerInformation.token = token;


    ua = new apiRTC.UserAgent({
            uri: 'apzkey:a5d17c5e5c9fdbdb42aa8312e1d12a0b'
    });

    $("#sessionStatus").text("Waiting for register response ");

    ua.register(registerInformation).then(uaRegistered)
    .catch(function (error) {
        debugger;
        console.log("Registration error");
        $("#sessionStatus").text("Failed to register UA");
    });

}

function uaRegistered(session) {
        debugger;
        console.log("Registration OK");
        connectedSession = session;
        $("#useragentId").text(useragentId);
        $("#sessionUsername").text(session.getUsername());
        $("#sessionStatus").text("Connected");

        debugger;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this issue in documentation, we have done a first update for using an external validation service here :

https://dev.apirtc.com/authentication/index

On client side, you need to use following code :

```
    registerInformation.token = "myToken"

    ua.register(registerInformation).then(function(session) {
        // Save session
        connectedSession = session;
    }).catch(function(error) {
        // error
        console.error('User agent registration failed', error);
    });
```

the usage of token in uri is for users authentication on Apizee offers

Comment: Thanks for the response Luart. When I try this way, neither then nor catch function is executed on ua.register. I have added updated code to the question.

Comment: Hello, I did some testings with your configuration and it seems that we have an issue to connect on your authent server : authenticationServerUrl :  https://serol.ro/checkToken
[2019-06-18T11:40:36.221] [ERROR] socketManager - { Error: unable to verify the first certificate
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1103:38)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:637:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:467:38) code: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE' }